# Parsing nested JSON with php for mysql

Tags: php, json

I have the following and I want to make sure I am doing this correctly.

```
"jobAssignments": [
{
  "id": 15797,
  "jobId": 15792,
  "jobNumber": "15792",
  "technician": {
    "id": 156,
    "name": "Mike"
  },
  "split": 100,
  "totalDrivingHours": 1680,
  "totalWorkingHours": 7680,
  "assignedOn": "2015-11-05T09:08:22.5680879",
  "status": "Done"
}
],
```

and then my php file reads the following

```
$jobassignresults = array();
foreach($data['jobAssignments']['technician'] as $chunk){
    $jatech = $chunk['technician'];
    $jatechid = $jatech['id'];
    $jatechname = $jatech['name'];
    $jobassignreults[] = ($jatechid, $jatechname);
}
$jasplit = $data['jobAssignments']['split'];
$jadriving = $data['jobAssignments']['totalDrivingHours'];
$jaworking = $data['jobAssignments']['totalWorkingHours'];
```

it is possible to have more than 1 tech, if you do then the split would change, eventually the data will be pushed to a sql database is this the correct way to handle the json?

Comment: tl:dr: ...  change your outer foreach to: `foreach ($data['jobAssignments'] as $chunk) {...`.

Comment: @RyanVincent I think i understand what your saying, i have technician listed to many times and need to remove it from the main?